# Dax sum all fields with same value

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerbi, dax, measure

I am using Power BI and i would like to know how to sum all the fields of the same value, and then take the percentage out of the total.
For example:
I have the following table:

```
               Computer Name | Manufacturer | Errors
                     Comp1   |      Hp      |   4
                     Comp2   |      Dell    |   2
                     Comp3   |      Hp      |   1
                     Comp4   |      Asus    |   2
                     Comp5   |      Asus    |   2
```

I would like to create a measure that sums all the errors according to manufacturer, so basically it will sum all of the instances of the same value
and return something like this:

```
                     Manufaturer | Errors | Count comps
                         Asus    |   4    |    2
                         Hp      |   5    |    2
                         Dell    |   2    |    1
```

And in the end calculate the percentage out of max errors.

The part i cant figure is how to some all the errors for same field value.

Please help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `COUNTROWS()` and `SUM()` functions. Create two measures `Count comps` and `Sum Errors`.

Count comps`=COUNTROWS(Tabla1)`

Sum Errors `=SUM(Tabla1[Errors])`

In Excel, create a pivot table and call the created measures, like this:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: You can get a similar presentation to that Excel Pivot Table in Power BI, using the Table Visual.

Comment: You're right but while posting this answer I did not have access to Power BI. This approach still works for both PowerPivot or Power BI.